# Make 'processing-efficiency' tag a synonym of 'performance'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

There are 103 questions marked with this tag, and most of them (I checked the first page of questions for this tag) are really about [performance](/questions/tagged/performance).

I suggest making [processing-efficiency](/questions/tagged/processing-efficiency) a synonym of [performance](/questions/tagged/performance).